# Submitting an html form with bootstrap to php server side

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to submit a html form to php server side on same page, so when I use html free from bootstrap it works fine.

But when I mix some bootstrap tags I can't submit any something.
(the form supposed upload a file and submit it, beside a text).

```
<?php
echo '<div id="content" class="container" style="new.css">';
echo '<form action="Addproducts.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal well col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">';
echo '<input type="text" id="text" name="image_text"></input>';
echo ' <div class="form-group">';
echo '<input type="file" name="image"/>';   
echo '</div>'; 
echo ' <div class="form-group">';
echo ' <center> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter"/>  </center>';
echo ' </div>';  
echo '</form>';  
//end of html part
```

The php scripts part

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$dbHost  = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'mydb';    
$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");

$image_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli , $_POST['image_text']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"images/".$_FILES['image']['name']);
$path ="images/".$_FILES['image']['name'] ;
$imgContent = basename($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) ;

if($mysqli->connect_error)
{
die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}
$insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT into products(product_Image,product_name,Image_path) VALUES ('$imgContent','$image_text','$path' )");
$target = "images/".basename($image);
move_uploaded_file($image, $target) ; 

if($insert)
 {
echo "<center>Image inserted successfully</center>";
 }

else 
echo "<center> Error in inserting image </center>";
 }
echo ' </div>';

 ?>
```

The problem here when I trying to use bootstrap

```
<?php

echo '<div class="panel panel-primary">';
echo '<div class="panel-body">';  
echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal well col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">';

echo '<input type="text"   name="image_text" class="form-control"></input>';

echo ' <div class="form-group">';
echo '<input type="file" class="form-control" name="image"/>';
echo ' </div>';

echo ' <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter" /> ';

echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Why are you declaring this `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");` as your connection, but then doing `$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);`, I don't get it.

Comment: Normally the php script (server side) is executed before client side and i think you are trying to use bootstrap before it loads. try to echo = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">'; and than echo = '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>'; and echo = <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>'; at the begining

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve so here is a working form that will upload an image and add a row to a SQL table with the file name and product name.

```
<?PHP
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    // Database creds | Even in a DEV environment I would recomend setting up a username and password. It is good practise.
    $dbHost  = 'localhost';
    $dbUsername = 'mydb_write';
    $dbPassword = 'nZjf4cKh7XDkHmQg';
    $dbName = 'mydb';

    // Create the connection
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

    // Check the connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        // This will only be printed if there is a connection issue
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    // Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement
    $image_text = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['product_name']);

    // Insert the text and file name into the SQL table
    if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `products`(`product_Image`, `product_name`) VALUES ('" . $_FILES["product_image"]["name"] . "','" . $image_text . "')"))
    {
        // Move the file | You would want to do some validation of file type, file size etc.
        // https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp
        // https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'], __DIR__.'/images/'. $_FILES["product_image"]['name']))
        {
            // Display a success message
            echo "
            <div class='alert alert-success'>
              <strong>Success!</strong> The file has been uploaded.
            </div>        
        ";
        }
        else
        {
            // Display an error message
            echo "
            <div class='alert alert-danger'>
              <strong>ERROR!</strong> The file has NOT been uploaded.
            </div>        
        ";
        }
    }

    // Close the SQL connection
    $mysqli->close();
}
?>
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>PHP image form!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>Upload form test</h1>
                    <br /><br />
                    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-inline">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="product_image" name="product_image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control-file" name="product_name" placeholder="The product name..">
                        </div>
                        <br /><br />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-block">Upload</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The below is an export for a MySQL database for the table it inserts into. It is a good idea to have an id column so you can identify rows easier (there could be similar rows). A time stamp of when it was uploaded is also a good idea.

Both the ID & timestamp column are dealt with by SQL. You do not need to mention these columns in your PHP code.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Sep 08, 2018 at 11:38 AM
-- Server version: 10.1.34-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.2.8

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `mydb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `products`
--

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_Image` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_uploaded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `products`
--
ALTER TABLE `products`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `products`
--
ALTER TABLE `products`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

If you have issues with the file being uploaded, check the folder permissions.

I hope this helps.

Regards

edwoli

Comment: Thank you for reply

Comment: I changed the form part of .html file to  the following                                             
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control-file" name="image_text" placeholder="The file name..">
                        </div>

Comment: But I get  after posting the following                                     Array ( [image] => Array ( [name] => bitnami.ico [type] => image/x-icon [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpF8D5.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 1150 ) ) Array ( [image_text] => Edowli )

Comment: Yes, that was only to show you what the $_POST outputs are. You can now write you PHP code to use those attributes.

Comment: If you are not having any luck with the PHP script, let me know and I will knock up a working example.

Comment: I  used the same  php script I have posted   with  adding if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
   print_r($_FILES);
   print_r($_POST);  at the beginning of the script

Comment: I am new to Stack overflow. Can anyone let me know why my answers have been down voted?

Comment: I am old with stackoverflow I don't know also why my questions every time is down voted lol

Comment: However you should only post one answer & u can edit it i

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the first answer with the working example.